# accessing UITableView from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

hello i was optimizing my tableview and then i got lazytableimages project and modified it to work for my data... now i want to add uitabbarcontroller to the project.. But the problem is here
this code is in the end of AppDelegate.m which creates the vaiable of UItableViewController and then set the value of entries..

```
  // The root rootViewController is the only child of the navigation
  // controller, which is the window's rootViewController.
            RootViewController *rootViewController = (RootViewController*)[(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController topViewController];

            rootViewController.entries = weakParser.appRecordList;
```

this code is only accessing topviewcontroller from UINavigationController But when we add the tabBarController this code dont work.. i wanna know how can i access the tableview after adding uitabbarcontroller.
my hierarchy is --

1. UITabBarController:

   - UINavigationController

     - UITableViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the index of the UINavigationController in UITabBarController , you can do:

```
UITabBarController * tabBarVC = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;            
UINavigationController * nc = (UINavigationController *)tabBarVC.viewControllers[index];
RootViewController * rootViewController = (RootViewController *)nc.topViewController;
rootViewController.entries = weakParser.appRecordList;
```

but you can make your code more elegant by using NSNotification and updating the list of records in RootViewController.

So , instead of the code above , you can do:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"recordListDidFinish"   object:self userInfo:weakParser.appRecordList? @{@"recordList": weakParser.appRecordList}:nil];
```

And , in the method "viewDidLoad" of RootViewController , add these lines:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"recordListDidFinish" object:[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    self.entries = note.userInfo[@"recordList"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}];
```

In consequences, whatever you change the rootController of window to, your code always work.

Comment: that NSNotification code worked like a charm.. thanks alot.!!